# Best way to select DOM object using TweenLite/GSAP?

Tags: javascript, animation, gsap

I'm using [TweenLite](http://greensock.com/tweenlite) to build some banner advertisements. I have everything working fine, however I'm a bit confused on how an element is selected, or at least the best practice for selecting an element using TweenLite.

At first I was using this:

```
var logo = document.getElementById("logo");
```

to select the element and then animating with:

```
TweenLite.to(logo, .45, {transform:"1,1", right:"19px", delay:.6, ease:Quart.easeOut});
```

However, I found that the animation still works without declaring the #logo as a variable.

**My question is, which of the following is best to use?**

1. `var logo = document.getElementById("logo"); TweenLite.to(logo, .45,
   {transform:"1,1", right:"19px", delay:.6, ease:Quart.easeOut});`
   //Declare Variable and reference
2. `TweenLite.to(logo, .45, {transform:"1,1", right:"19px"});` 
   //Don't declare #logo a variable or use # to reference logo as an ID. Not sure why this works.
3. `TweenLite.to("#logo", .45, {transform:"1,1", right:"19px", delay:.6,
   ease:Quart.easeOut});`
   //Reference ID in script without creating or referencing a variable

Or is there another option that would be better that I'm not aware of, aside from using an additional js library? Is browser support the same for all of these?

I'm loading in the following libraries from GSAP:
css plugin
ease pack
tweenlite

Answer (score 2):

It is not clear what do you mean by "best way". You mean Performance-friendly way? Or user friendly way? In programming overall, be direct as possible. Do not create unecessary variables (you will avoid memory leaks and performance gets better).

If you are NOT willing to use logo object just for single tween, use variable as storage:

```
var logo = document.getElementById("logo");
TweenLite.to(logo, .45, {transform:"1,1", right:"19px"});
```

Greensock selector is elegant, but it must process string in order to select object:

```
TweenLite.to("#logo", .45, {transform:"1,1", right:"19px", delay:.6, ease:Quart.easeOut});
```

If you are willing to use logo object just for this single tween and be performance friendly, be direct:

```
TweenLite.to(document.getElementById("logo"), .45, {transform:"1,1", right:"19px", delay:.6, ease:Quart.easeOut});
```

Answer (score 0):

in my opinion the best method is by creating variables. This way if you have an animation you can always call on the variable rather then re-typing the id/class, in which GSAP is searching again for the object.